# What is a "top-level" in web in general?

Tags: top-level-domains, browsers

If I'm not wrong, a "top-level" is a browser window; or shall I say a "browser-window object", which parents the "document object" which parents "head" and "body" HTML objects (and so forth).

Am I wrong?

Comment: "Top level" isn't a general concept.  "Top level domain" and "top level browser window" have separate meanings that are not very related.

Answer (score 1):

Top-Level can apply to the term "top-level attributes":

- A browser orders objects chronologically based on its HTML ordering.
- You can also add layers to objects using `z-index` to determine which layer is the top-level.

Top-level also applies to domain endings (like `.com`). If the domain address is `sub.example.com` than formally, the top-level domain of the domain `example.com` would be `.com`.